# OData cannot perform filter IN operation on not nullable integer

Tags: c#, integer, odata

It is not possible to filter data, if there is Foreign Key with not nullable integer. 
By calling this

```
/api/Shops/106/Lines?$filter=shopid in (104, 106)
```

there is this Error:

```
ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int64]' of method 'Boolean Contains[Int64](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int64], Int64)'
```

Answer (score 1):

IN works fine if I do it against FK object
(eg. $filter=Shop.Id in (2,3)), but In some cases, using the / notation may work when the . notation does not.

Following query works

```
/api/Shops/106/Lines?$filter=Shop/Id in (104, 106)
```